# Revolution slider video is stopped

Tags: video, slider, revolution-slider

I have a video added to a website by Revolution Slider. 
The video is added as a content layer, it has a background image. The problem is that after 15-20 minutes the videos stops playing and the background image is shown. The video should never stop. Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, i have 3 videos in a sequence, they play well for about 2/3 minutes, then the plyback stops